# Google Cloud SQL connection is always null (NullPointerException)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying out a new app on app-engine. The app basically does some operations on Cloud SQL and displays the results on the app side. Everything works perfectly fine locally. That is i'm able to connect to local MySql db, create connection to the db and manipulate data on it. But when the app is deployed to app-engine i'm always getting NullPointerException as the Connection object returned as a result of this line :-

connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-   id:your-instance-name/htlaets?user=root"); 
is always null.

I'm very sure that my project id and instance name are correct.

- I have enabled the google connector in appengine-web.xml.
- Have authorized my app for the SQL instance.
- Both the db and app are in the same region.
- Also, i'm able to connect to this instance(First generation) through my MySql Client application.

I don't know what wrong I'm doing here. Can someone please suggest how solve this ?

Comment: Update - Found the actual cause. It's because of this - SQLException - java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

But, this shouldn't be happening as password for root is not required in production environment. Any reason why this may be happening ?

Comment: Finally found the solution. Didn't think it would be this simple.
I had set the password for root@localhost user when setting up the DB.
Changed the password to blank. This solved the issue.